# Nuxt/Image - what is the difference in fit="inside/outside"

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, nuxt.js, image-optimization

What is the difference between those keys, as [per documentation](https://image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img#fit)

"inside: Preserving aspect ratio, resize the image to be as large as possible while ensuring its dimensions are less than or equal to both those specified."

"outside: Preserving aspect ratio, resize the image to be as small as possible while ensuring its dimensions are greater than or equal to both those specified."

How should I understand it? Lets say in reference to

"cover: (default) Preserving aspect ratio, ensure the image covers both provided dimensions by cropping/clipping to fit"

Which does not say that the image is resized, is it not than? And what is the use case for inside and outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach to solve this is probably to go Unplash and pick a portrait photo like this one: https://unsplash.com/photos/wQe5nEi5zG4

Bring it into the `/static` directory of Nuxt and load this in your page with the following

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-img fit="cover" src="/flower.jpg" width="800" height="200" />
    <nuxt-img fit="inside" src="/flower.jpg" width="800" height="200" />
    <nuxt-img fit="outside" src="/flower.jpg" width="800" height="200" />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
img {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Then, you'll see that `cover` is mainly `object-fit="cover"` as explained [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#cover).

It will be quite somehow cropped by the smaller size of the div.

[image]

---

The other 2 are a bit more tricky to understand but it's easier if you see the actual result with the devtools.

In the `network` tab, you can see that the size is quite different (the order of the images is conserved).

[image]

If you go to the `Elements` tab and check the value there, you'll be able to see that the image will:

- `keep it's aspect ratio`
- `resize itself to be at MAXIMUM 200px wide` (minimum out from 800 and
  200)

Hence why the final's image size (intrinsic size) is 133 x 200px.

[image]

---

The other one will be the opposite:

- `keep it's aspect ratio`
- `resize itself to be at MINIMUM at 800px wide` (maximum out from 800 and 200).

This one will be quite more HD, with 800 x 1200px.

[image]